# SIM800L CREG AT command returns 0,2 when no SIM and 0,0 when SIM is inserted

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, gsm

I have an SIM800L module. It is connected up in the same way as [this website shows,](https://lastminuteengineers.com/sim800l-gsm-module-arduino-tutorial/)( i.e 10K resistor from Rx to Arduino data-pin and 20K resistor from Rx to ground.)

Only difference is I'm using an 18650.

I've checked the voltage and got the module to print out the battery status on the serial monitor, and everything seems fine. I put a SIM card in there (one that I used with my smartphone) which was Vodafone. T-Mobile network was the only one that was coming up as available operators for some reason.

The output that I get from the SIM800L is this below.

I can never get the SIM800L to register to a network, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm a n00b and this is my first time trying something like this.

[image]

Comment: The most likely cause is that the battery voltage drops when the module transmits.  Do you have a power supply that can deliver the same voltage but more current?

Comment: Was testing with the multimeter and put neg on the neg of the battery and pos just past the 10K resistor on the Rx and when there is a transmission, it drops from 5.1V to 2.8V.... but I guess the current as you mentioned would still be an issue. Perhaps I can put 2 18650s in parallel to deliver more current?

Comment: The voltage drop shows that your battery can't deliver enough current.

Comment: What would be the best thing to do JRE? Sorry I'm a bit clueless as this is my first time and I'm just learning about electronics!

Comment: Also, CREG only asks the registration state.  You'll probably have to send the CPIN command to check the state of the PIN , and send the PIN if needed.

Comment: 18650 cells in parallel can cause problems if not done correctly.

Comment: Do you have an antenna attached?

Comment: Yeah, I've actually got 2 attached, one which is the NET one (the curly one) and the other which is just a long wire with a board on the end.

Comment: I tried doing AT+COPS=2 to deregister from the network but now AT+COPS=? returns ERROR :(

Comment: OK I did CREG = 1 and it seems to be back to where I started i.e. CREG 0, 0, COPS is now 0. Shall I try the CPIN command?

Comment: btw CPIN? comes back as READY